# Is there a more efficient method to process large amounts of data than through arrays?

Tags: python, arrays, data-structures

Hej there, I am writing a data aquisition and analysis software to a physical measurement set up with Python. In the process I gather massive amounts of data points (easily in the order of 1.000.000 or more) which I subsequently will analyze. So far I am using arrays of float numbers, which in principle do the job.
However, I am getting strange effects on the aquired data as I use more and more data points per measurement, which makes me wonder wether the handling of the arrays is so inefficient, that writing into them makes for a significant time delay in the data aquisition loop.

Is that a possibility? Do you have any suggestions about how to improve the handling time in the writing process (it is a matter of microseconds) or is that not a possible influence and I need to look somewhere else?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you add a table of the needed time versus array length?

Comment: Could you give some examples of the strange effects you mention?

Comment: You have only in the order of 1.000.000 data points (so in der order of a few MB o data). This is actually not a very large amount of data.

Answer (score 5):

Do you mean lists? You can use [NumPy](http://new.scipy.org/getting-started.html) to handle numerical arrays efficient and performant.

From the NumyPy website:

> First of all, they are great for performing calculation relying
>   heavily on mathematical and numerical operations. They can work
>   natively with matrices and arrays, perform operations on them, find
>   eigenvectors, compute integrals, solve differential equations.
>
> NumPy’s array class (which is used to implement the matrix class) is
>   implemented with speed in mind, so accessing NumPy arrays is faster
>   than accessing Python lists. Further, NumPy implements an array
>   language, so that most loops are not needed.

Comment: Lists in python are implemented as arrays.